# how to remove Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, wampserver

I am having following error on using curlas extension

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www***\index.php on line 15

---

I have following configuration

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll 
extension=php_curl.dll 
;extension=php_dba.dll
```

i installed 
    ***wampserver2.2e-php5.4.3-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64.exe***

i tried to enable other extension also and restarted server but they local host is not able to load that extension.

Comment: Are those extension directives really all on one line? If so, it is invalid (and commented out anyway)

Comment: Also, be sure you are modifying the correct php.ini.  Check the output of `phpinfo()` to see _which_ php.ini file is being loaded, and load the extension in that one.

Comment: Are you trying to load a page through a browser on your local machine, or execute a script via command-line?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski not in single line...it was in stackoverflow code...      another thing , yes i verified all available php.ini... although i corrected ini which was refernced in phpinfo()

Comment: @newfurniturey using browser on local machine....

Answer (score 2):

If you're experiencing this issue when you execute PHP command-line with wamp server, it's because PHP does not hold a reference to the wamp-modified `php.ini` file (only the apache instance does). Without it, things like `curl` will not work properly.

To fix this, you need to copy the `php.ini` file from the Apache folder to the PHP folder.

- Apache Path: [wamp install dir]\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini
- PHP Path: [wamp install dir]\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini

You can update the apache/php versions in the folder-paths if yours don't match.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions:

1. Enable the plugin

   - in wamp this is done in the right click menu.
   - On Linux - it'll probably be in php.ini (though don't forget to restart Apache!)
2. Check curl exists before attempting to use it:

   - `if(!function_exists('curl_init')) echo "cURL not installed. Trying something else...";`

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line in the php.ini

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

And remember to set the extensions directory in your php.ini

```
extension_dir = “/usr/local/php5/ext”
```

Answer (score 0):

There is solution with all necessary details:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qNTi1sEfE8

It is in French, but you can understand everything! I solved same problem, even don't speak French. :-)

Many answers forget to mention that you need to add new version of php_curl.dll file from this location: 
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

I added new version of php_curl.dll from archive php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip to folders:
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext   and    C:\Windows\System32
and everything was fine!